# MVC fool proof validation error inside the JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, customvalidator

I downloaded MVC Fool Proof Validation from http://foolproof.codeplex.com/

Beacuse I am in need of [RequiredIf].

When I installed MVC Fool Proof Validation I recieved three Javascript files

which are these that I am using inside my layout:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Problem is that when I check my scripts with Chrome I get the following errors on these these JS files.

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'adapters' of undefined mvcfoolproof.unobtrusive.min.js:54
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ValidatorRegistry' of undefined MvcFoolproofValidation.min.js:50
```

This is the error on the first one

[image]

Second error:

[image]

I have not even edited anything inside the JS files :S
Any solutions is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you included the scripts before you include jQuery. You should include jQuery before these scripts

Comment: Right :) But Now I am recieving another error I updated the picture with the new error

Comment: If I look at [foolproof.codeplex.com](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) I do not see the same scripts that you use. I think you should check which validation you want to use and use the scripts as recommended by that page

Comment: I got this scripts when I installed Fool Proof, I did not recieve those from the page. I guess he didnt update his page.

Comment: You are including 3 scripts. In the foolproof page there is a section about Client Validation. Have a look there which scripts to include, in which order and for which validation you want to use

Answer (score 1):

Be careful using FoolProof RequiredIf in MVC4.

This works:
[RequiredIfTrue("lead_recommendation", ErrorMessage="required")]

This does not:
[RequiredIfTrue("lead_recommendation", ErrorMessage="Required")]

I spent hours racking my brain on this.

Comment: Seems to be the case with all/most/many strings passed as values to an attribute property to Foolproof attributes. To be safe, I always use initial capital letters nowadays on its validation attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Do the below steps:

- Step 1:

PM> Install-Package MicrosoftAjax

- Step 2:

PM> Install-Package MicrosoftMvcAjax.Mvc5

- Step 3:

Include them in bundleconfig like below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/mvcFoolProof").Include(
                          "~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax*",
                          "~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax*",
                          "~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation*",
                          "~/Scripts/mvcfoolproof*",
                          "~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofJQueryValidation*",                                            
                          "~/Scripts/MvcFoolproofValidation*"));
```

Now it should work without any errors.